# C++ If-else statement using strings and comparing strings

Tags: c++, if-statement

when I enter (Im qwerty) as (y), the program shows "Your account has been deactivated" instead of "Your password is incorrect". I've searched for same problems but *const. char* and using *strcmp* is too complicated for me and my instructor does not use that kinds of codes.I'm very eager to know what must I do to make my program right. (Tnx in advance)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {
string y;
cout << "Enter Icode: ";
cin >> y;


if (y == "Im qwerty")
    cout << "Your password is incorrect.";

else
    cout << "Your account has been deactivated.";



cin.get();
return 0;

}
```

Comment: but when y = "I'm qwerty", it's not "I'm robbee" - so why would you expect it to say "incorrect"?

Comment: It should naturally go to the else condition as `"I'm qwerty"` is not equal to `"Im robbee"`

Comment: strcmp is for C, use y.compare("Im qwerty") != 0)

Comment: The problem you ask can be solved using a debugger;  Can I suggest you read [this](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) which will help you resolve other issues in the future

Comment: Did you consider printing out the value of `y` to see what it is? "There is a problem with my thing" then _look at the thing_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `cin >> y;` reads one word, whereas there are two words in `"Im qwerty"`. In other words, this program always outputs `"Your account has been deactivated."` because one word never matches two words.

If you would like to read multiple words, the easiest is to read an entire line, e.g. replace `cin >> y;` with `getline(cin, y);`.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. @Maxim

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: I am not your "sweetheart".